# Wordpress Categories and SubCategories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-list-categories

I am doing some changes on my blog theme, and i need to list the subcategories when user is inside the parent category, example:

- main-category
  -- subcat1
  -- subcat2

So i need to show the subcat1 and subcat2 only when the user is inside main-category. At this moment i have 2 divs, one for the main-categories (this is what i need users to see on all pages) and one div bellow the main-category div to show the subcategories.

Is this possible? I am sorry for my English, let me know if this is too confuse.

Thanks for your time.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible using [get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) and [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) with the `child_of` parameter.  Use something like the following on your main-category page:

```
$category = get_the_category();
wp_list_categories('child_of=' . $category[0]->cat_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

try with a function `<?php echo list_categories(); ?>`

```
$categories = get_categories($args);
$html       = '';
foreach($categories as $cat){
if($cat->category_parent == 0){
$html .= '';<--- your code
$childCategories = get_categories('child_of='.$cat->cat_ID.'');
if(!empty($childCategories)){
foreach($childCategories as $ccat){
$html .= '';<-- your code'
```

`}}} $html .=''; 
return $html;}`

for get more childrens only add the new variable and get the categories of her child_of