# Wordpress - Subcategory templating

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im sure this is a pretty common question around here, so sorry if I am repeating a similar question already answered.

So I thought id have a dabble at creating my first Wordpress theme.
I've created the template I would like to use for parent categories, now Im trying to work out how to create a template for sub-categories.

I've put all my parent category HTML in the categories.php file, should I be putting my sub-category HTML in the same file and adding some PHP to differentiate between parent and child categories (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571417/wordpress-categories-and-subcategories)) or is there a different method I should use that I haven't uncovered yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's still just a category, use `category-mysubcategory.php` and it will be more explicit than the fall back to the `category-parent.php` template file.

Comment: Hi Ohgodwhy,

so would I put the code I currently have in my category in a new file named category-<slug>.php and do the same with sub-categories? 

Makes sense actually.

Comment: Yep that's all there is to it

Comment: Thanks ;) Feel free to summarise in an answer and ill mark it best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, the specificity of the templating engine is handled by category name, regardless of any type of hierarchy in the category.

Therefore by targeting the category slug, you'll be able to theme it independent of the parent(s).

```
category-mysubcategory.php
```

Where `mysubcategory` is the `slug` of your category.

Comment: Sorry Ohgodwhy, one last thing. Would I have to do this for every category I create? Somehow I feel like we are missing something :P